# Lithium: Correct use of select2 with `multiple` option

Tags: jquery-select2, lithium

by using Lithium form helper we can insert a `select` tag that a single item can be selected.

sample:

```php
echo $this->form->field('myfield', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'list' => array(
        'id1' => 'value1',
        'id2' => 'value2',
        ),
    )
);
```

Now if you want to use `Select2` jQuery plugin with `multiple` option, `field` method in `form helper` tries to retrieve submitted value in string.
even when `multiple` option is set!

non-working sample:

```php
echo $this->form->field('myfield', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'list' => array(
        'id1' => 'value1',
        'id2' => 'value2',
        ),
    'multiple' => true,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`field` method won't accept array value in submitted forms.

so try `select` method in Form Helper with a `multiple` option.

sample code:

```php
echo $this->form->select('myfield', 
    array(
         'id1' => 'value1',
         'id2' => 'value2',
    ),
    array(
        'multiple' => true,
    )
);
```